# Copy a MySQL table including indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, create-table

I can copy a MySQL table to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

This works, but the indexes are not copied to the new table. How can I copy a table including the indexes?