# MySQL ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './"DatabaseName/Table.frm' (errno: 13)

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups

Can you create a copy of a table by simply making a duplicate of .frm file?
I intend to do something like this:

Suppose my database's name is mydb and it has a table called mytab.
Browse to the folder named mydb in the file system and it has a mytab.frm file.
Then copy the contents of mytab.frm into a file called copy.frm 
Then i login to mysql and run the following commands:

```
use mydb;  //Selects the database mydb
show tables; //To see the list of tables. I can see the table named copy.
select * from copy; //This throws the error mentioned in the title.
```

So what am I missing? What files do you copy to take the backup of a database?
I know that table can be copied by a couple of sql statements But i want to learn something knew so I am experimenting around. Thanks! :)

Comment: Duplicated. Have a look at this question with the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415855/run-mysql-create-table-by-select-another-and-copied-the-indexes-automatically

Comment: @itinance It''s not a duplicate. I am not using sql commands to create a copy. I am copying a file into another in file system to create a copy of the table.

Comment: errno 13 is permission denied. Check the permissions. And, also, stop doing that. Use sql commands or mysql utilities to copy tables.

Comment: here's a better idea. `create table copy as select * from mytab`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` is better than hacking files but it does not produce an exact copy of the table. The field types are inferred (`CHAR` and `VARCHAR` fields are shrunk to the minimum, null-able and`DEFAULT` properties are lost and so on) and the new table does not have any index. Use `CREATE TABLE LIKE` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throwing this down as an answer:

You can't do what you have tried for InnoDB tables. InnoDB stores all table data in a single file - ibdata.  You can modify this with the `innodb_file_per_table` setting in my.cnf, but it isn't retroactive, it will only apply to new tables. Even if you DO have file per table setup, you still shouldnt try and just copy the data files, because innodb may not have flushed all changes from the ib_logfile's to the ibdata / .ibd file, so you could well end up with corrupt data.

You can do it for MyISAM tables but you shouldn't (and there are also other files that to be copied as well, as the .FRM is only the table definition. The .MYD file contains the data and the .MYI file contains the indexes). Why? because you are entrusting your data to a database, you should be using database tools to duplicate it.  The only time you should be touching the data files directly is during data recovery, and only when the server is not running - you dont want to be copying the files as they're being written to.

To duplicate a table, simply do this:

`create table new_table as select * from old_table`

To backup an entire database, use `mysqldump` or one of the other available backup tools.

Comment: There you go. That's got to be the strangest downvote i've ever seen.

Comment: This answers clears everything up! Great! Thanks. I don't know who downvoted you but I upvote your answer and select it as my solution! :D

Comment: `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` does not create an exact copy of the table. Only the field names of the new table are copied from the old table (in fact, they are copied from the resultset produced by `SELECT`); the types of the fields are roughly the same as on the source table but the details (signed/unsigned, length, null-able, default value) are not copied (because they do not appear in the source result set). No indexes are created for the new table.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Copying/moving MySQL tables by altering the underlying files is possible in some conditions but it is highly **unrecommended**.

**Always** use `MySQL` commands to do it.

---

The `.frm` file contains only the table definition. The data and the indexes are stored in other files and they depend on the storage engine of the table.

Several excerpts from the official documentation:

#### [`MyISAM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

> [**15.2 The MyISAM Storage Engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)
>
> Each `MyISAM` table is stored on disk in three files. The files have names that begin with the table name and have an extension to indicate the file type. An `.frm` file stores the table format. The data file has an `.MYD` (MYData) extension. The index file has an `.MYI` (MYIndex) extension.

#### [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html)

> [**14.1 Introduction to InnoDB**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-introduction.html)
>
> By default, with the [`innodb_file_per_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) setting enabled, each new `InnoDB` table and its associated indexes are stored in a separate file. When the [`innodb_file_per_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) option is disabled, InnoDB stores all its tables and indexes in the single system tablespace, which may consist of several files (or raw disk partitions).
>
> [**14.2.15.1 Role of the .frm File for InnoDB Tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-frm-file.html)
>
> MySQL stores its data dictionary information for tables in `.frm` files in database directories. Unlike other MySQL storage engines, `InnoDB` also encodes information about the table in its own internal data dictionary inside the tablespace. When MySQL drops a table or a database, it deletes one or more `.frm` files as well as the corresponding entries inside the `InnoDB` data dictionary. You **cannot move** `InnoDB` tables between databases simply by moving the `.frm` files.

> [**14.12 InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html)
>
> [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table)
>
> When `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled (the default in 5.6.6 and higher), `InnoDB` stores the data and indexes for each newly created table in a separate `.ibd` file, rather than in the [`system tablespace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_system_tablespace).

> [**MySQL Glossary**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html)
>
> [**system tablespace**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_system_tablespace)
>
> One or more data files (`ibdata` files) containing the metadata for InnoDB-related objects (the data dictionary), and the storage areas for the undo log, the change buffer, and the doublewrite buffer. Depending on the setting of the `innodb_file_per_table`, when tables are created, it might also contain table and index data for some or all `InnoDB` tables. The data and metadata in the system tablespace apply to all the databases in a MySQL instance.
>
> Prior to MySQL 5.6.7, the default was to keep all InnoDB tables and indexes inside the system tablespace, (...) In MySQL 5.6.7 and higher, the default is `file-per-table` mode, where each table and its associated indexes are stored in a separate `.ibd` file.

### Let's draw some (partial) conclusion

**Before anything else you have to stop the MySQL server (to be sure all the data is safely stored into files).**

If the table you want to copy uses the `MyISAM` engine then you need to copy/rename the `.frm`, `.MYD` and `.MYI` files having the same name as the table.

If the table uses the `InnoDB` engine **and** at the moment when it was created the `innodb_file_per_table` setting was `ON` then you need to copy/rename the `.frm` and `.ibd` files having the same name as the table.

If the table uses the `InnoDB` engine and it was created while the `innodb_file_per_table` setting was `OFF` then you **cannot** copy or move the table data from outside MySQL.

If the table uses the `MEMORY` table then it's enough to copy the `.frm` file and restart the server. The table data and indexes are stored in memory, there is no file for them and the source table will be empty after the server restart, so you get an exact copy of an empty table ;-)

### But wait, there is more!

MySQL implements several [other storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html) that are probably less used than the ones mentioned above. Each of them has its own rules of storing the data in files.

### And more

If the server you want to hack this way is part of a [replication cluster](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) the changes you do either are ignored (do not propagate to the other servers in the cluster if you change a slave server) or break the replication (the slave servers are required to query and update a table they don't have, if you change the master server).

### The conclusion

Even if, in certain conditions, copying or moving a table by changing the underline files is possible, it is strongly **not recommended**.

The correct (and many times the only) way to copy a table is to use the commands provided by MySQL.

> [**13.1.14 CREATE TABLE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)
>
> Use `LIKE` to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:
>
> `CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;`
>
> The copy is created using the same version of the table storage format as the original table. The [`SELECT` privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select) is required on the original table.

You can then use:

```
INSERT INTO `new_tbl` SELECT * FROM `orig_tbl`
```

to copy the data.

#### Another way

An alternative way to copy a table without writing SQL commands is to export the table definition and data using [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html), open the export file in a text editor, change the table name in all the places where it appears, save the file and import it into the database using the [`mysql` command line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) (or other `MySQL` client).

Answer (score -1):

You have to copy 3 files:   copy.frm  copy.MYD  copy.MYI
Make privileges for files, owner and group 
 chown mysql.mysql copy.*
 chmod 660 copy.*
and refresh tables in mysql :
 mysql DATABASE
mysql> flush tables;

and voila!

Comment: unless its an innodb table.

Comment: I think innodb use one file for database

Comment: @badjack There are no .MYD or .MYI files. It's an innodb table. There is a .opt file anyhow. Can you tell me what exactly are the contents of .MYD and .MYI files and why should I be copying them?

Comment: MYD is the table data for a MyISAM table, MYI is the index file for a MyISAM table. FRM is the table definition file for both.  Innodb defaults to all tables in a single file, but there's a db setting to change it to one file per table. It isn't retroactive.  The only way to do what you want with an innodb table is with my comment against your original question.

Comment: @pala_ I was just experimenting around so I wanted to avoid using sql statements! But thanks for the info.  :)

Comment: @SoniaSaxena what os are you using for mysql?

Comment: The SQL is the correct way (and many times the only way) to do it.

Comment: @axiac Hahaha...sounds deep! :P

Comment: @MiyaG I use ubuntu 12.04. I haven't upgraded my OS yet. The latest version is ubuntu 14.10 or something.

Comment: @SoniaSaxena  as in your question `Can you create a copy of a table by simply making a duplicate of .frm file? I intend to do something like this:` yes you can create a duplicate table with copying of `.frm, .MYI, .MYD' in MyISAM db.

Comment: @MiyaG But I get the error as mentioned in the title when I just copy the .frm file! Could it be an issue with permissions?

Comment: @SoniaSaxena... what method are you using to create duplicate table.. e.g. mysql command OR directly from database directory?