# mysql copy table doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli, copy, create-table

I'm using PHP to copy table for backup.

Code is simple.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //  BACKUP TABLE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE SerialTable3");
mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE SerialTable3 LIKE SerialTable2");
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SerialTable3 (SELECT * FROM SerialTable2)");

mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE SerialTable2");
mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE SerialTable2 LIKE SerialTable1");
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SerialTable2 (SELECT * FROM SerialTable1)");

mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE SerialTable1");
mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE SerialTable1 LIKE SerialTable");
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SerialTable1 (SELECT * FROM SerialTable)");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Drop table works as I confirm.
Create Table also works.

But Insert SQL doesn't work...
I saw a lot of other people doing this to copy table. But in my case, never works...

I know it's all same but I tried

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SerialTable1 SELECT * FROM SerialTable");
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SerialTable1 AS SELECT * FROM SerialTable");
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SerialTable1 AS (SELECT * FROM SerialTable)");
```

What's wrong?
As dropping and creating works, connection has no problem too.

Comment: this should work : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2415879/724913

Comment: May be the column names are missing ... you tried added columns of the table in your insert query before fetching the values from the other table?

Comment: How do I confirm error message? I'm working on hosting server. And remote access from other IP is not allowed in my hosting server. So I can't confirm error message from MySQL

Comment: Oh.. I forgot to add other tries. Yes. I tried to add columns as well... still doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415855/run-mysql-create-table-by-select-another-and-copied-the-indexes-automatically look here this is the same Problem i think, and it's solved

Comment: Try use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to retrieve the last mysql error, to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I just confirmed that mysqli_error() returns nothing. I have a guess.. Isn't this perhaps because insert SQL and Create SQL are running in 2 different thread? And maybe insert SQL will work before create SQL work? Is my guess possible?

Comment: I just found that it could be the problem caused by wordpress. I'm working on wordpress website adding new custom theme. Maybe mysqli_query is connected to some callback function as wordpress function. I'm really noob of wordpress. Any help?

Comment: [Solved!]It was about wordpress issue. all of my mysqli_query was excuting twice so all of my logic was messed up. Everytime when I use mysqli_query, $wpdb object automatically excute my query once more. It was my problem. And I just changed all of my code using mysqli_query to $wpdb->query()