# Unable to create a table in RDS MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a new table in Sys DB in RDS MySQL8.0 instance after logging in using the master username and password from a Linux server. But I am getting the following error * Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'sys'*. This user is having all the privileges granted. But still getting the above error. Could someone advise on what is the issue here?

Comment: I'm not sure about the limitations of Amazon, but have you tried the root user or is that only something they get?

Comment: Wait .. i just read that again .. why are you messing with the sys database?  It has all the info of your database, this is like asking why can't I update the boot record of my file system, you might be able to but one mistake and its broken.  Why not make a table in a different database, perhaps one you created?

Comment: Is it possible to create a copy of Sys database and play with the new DB with relevant tables?

Comment: I think you could copy it, but changing settings in the copy likely won't do anything, and most of the settings for the sys db are created by the db itself., and thus are more of a report of settings than something you can tinker.  I think a copy of it would only be useful for backup purposes, and being much of the content in there is created by the database its self, changing one thing could break the whole database system.

Comment: You could do this though :
CREATE TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME  
SELECT * FROM SOURCEDB.SOURCETABLE

Comment: ^ that makes a copy of the table that you could play with those values in that new table without breaking the original, however note, it does not copy the primary key setting, so you will have to set the column that is the primary key to auto increment and all that after you copy it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use,
USE sys;
SHOW TABLES;

this technique may work for you.

My testing with MariaDB does not give me access to a SYS. database.

To copy the table with indexes and data view this URL

[Copy a MySQL table including indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415855/copy-a-mysql-table-including-indexes)

and scroll down to Mar 10, 201 at 9:53  for raveren's Answer.

Prefix the 'old_table' name with sys.  on both lines.

Tread carefully, this will not WRECK your system but give you data
that was current when you copied the table's contents.